# thymeleaf custom tag with contents

Tags: templates, tags, thymeleaf

I'm new to thymeleaf and I'm trying to create a web component. What I want is something as this:

```
<components:panel><div>hi!</div></components:panel>
```

translated to something like this:

```
<div class="panel"><div class="contents"><div>hi!</div></div></div>
```

I've been trying to extend an AbstractElementTagProcessor, but I can't seem to figure out how to get the tags inside the processed tag:

```
public class PanelTagProcessor extends AbstractElementTagProcessor { 

    private static final String ELEMENT_NAME = "panel"; 
    private static final int PRECEDENCE = 10000; 

    public PanelTagProcessor(final String dialectPrefix) { 
        super(TemplateMode.HTML, "components", ELEMENT_NAME, true, null, false, PRECEDENCE); 
    } 

    @Override 
    protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext context, IProcessableElementTag tag, 
        IElementTagStructureHandler structureHandler) { 

        // How could I surround contents inside the tag with custom nodes? 

    } 
}
```

I'd be grateful if someone could help me :)

Regards 
Luis

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, I don't think it's possible to do with just a AbstractElementTagProcessor.  According to [the documentation](http://www.thymeleaf.org/apidocs/thymeleaf/3.0.3.RELEASE/org/thymeleaf/processor/IProcessor.html), those kind of processors "execute on open/standalone tag events only (no processors can be applied to close tags), and have no (direct) access to the element body."

I managed to get it working which an `AbstractElementModelProcessor` ("execute on complete elements, including their bodies, in the form of IModel objects"), so here is what worked for me.

```
public class PanelTagProcessor extends AbstractElementModelProcessor {

  private static final String TAG_NAME = "panel";
  private static final int PRECEDENCE = 10000;

  public PanelTagProcessor(String dialectPrefix) {
    super(TemplateMode.HTML, dialectPrefix, TAG_NAME, true, null, false, PRECEDENCE);
  }

  @Override
  protected void doProcess(ITemplateContext itc, IModel imodel, IElementModelStructureHandler iemsh) {
    IModelFactory modelFactory = itc.getModelFactory();
    imodel.replace(0, modelFactory.createOpenElementTag("div", "class", "panel"));
    imodel.insert(1, modelFactory.createOpenElementTag("div", "class", "contents"));
    imodel.insert(imodel.size() - 2, modelFactory.createCloseElementTag("div"));
    imodel.replace(imodel.size() - 1, modelFactory.createCloseElementTag("div"));
  }
}
```