# Pass Thymeleaf block content as variable to fragment

Tags: java, html, spring, thymeleaf

I'm trying to create a fragment that represents a card with custom content. I would like to do something like:

```
<div class="card" th:fragment="myfragment" th:utext="${content}">
</div>
```

And then use as

```
<th:block th:replace="myfragment">
   <p>Some custom content that would be the value of 'content'</p>
</th:block>
```

This would make it a lot easier to work with bigger html that would be kinda ugly to write in an attribute. (Basically I'm looking for a similar functionality to Blade's views and slots)

**EDIT:**
I'm aware of fragment parameterisation but passing long and complex html code in an attribute is pretty ugly and hard to manage.

A more descriptive example would be a card where the card body is not a p but a table for example.

Comment: Have you looked at thymeleaf-layout-dialect?

Comment: Thymeleaf supports parameterized fragments. https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/articles/layouts.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Soo, maybe not the best solution but I managed to get this working based on this [Other SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46074574/how-to-get-body-of-tag-in-processor-for-a-custom-dialect-in-thymeleaf-3-0-x) and this
[Example code](https://www.javatips.net/api/thymeleaf-master/thymeleaf-3.0-master/src/main/java/org/thymeleaf/standard/processor/AbstractStandardFragmentInsertionTagProcessor.java)

I've created a new dialect so I can say this:

```
<zms:card header="'ASD Title'">
   <div th:text="${first_name}"></div>
   asdasd card works asdasd
</zms:card>
```

And it will render this:

```
<div class="card shadow mb-4">
    <div class="card-header py-3">
        <div class="d-inline-block">
            <h6 class="m-0 font-weight-bold">ASD Title</h6>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-body">
        <div>Name</div>
        asdasd card works 
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this. It is really unfortunate that has to be the solution. This should really be a feature of Thymleaf... the use case for stuff like this is so common.

Answer (score 0):

Thymeleaf supports parameterized fragments. Here's how you can use it:

**Fragment Definition:**

```
_fragments/my_fragments.html:

<th:block th:fragment="myFragment(p1, p2, p3)">
   //do sth with p1, p2, p3
</th:block>
```

**Using it:**

```
<th:block th:replace="_fragments/my_fragments :: myFragment(${p1}, ${p2}, ${p3} )">
</th:block>
```

Ref:

- https://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2020/09/thymeleaf-pass-parameter-to-fragment.html
- https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#parameterizable-fragment-signatures
- https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-web-application-seed/blob/master/main-app/src/main/resources/templates/_fragments/_utils.html

Comment: I am aware of this and it works if my content is a simple p with some text but it would be really ugly to toss a long and complex html code in there.

Comment: It works for complex object graph as well.. not just the string . Here's one example https://github.com/gtiwari333/spring-boot-web-application-seed/blob/master/main-app/src/main/resources/templates/_fragments/_utils.html

Comment: But how do you give value to variable? Can I say something like var = "some HTML code" without doing this in my controller and handleing html as string?

Comment: https://ganeshtiwaridotcomdotnp.blogspot.com/2020/09/thymeleaf-pass-parameter-to-fragment.html See this. You can pass a constant value from Thymeleaf or a value received from server.

Comment: This has nothing to do with my problem. See my answer below for what I wanted to achieve. I am completely aware that the content can be passed as a thymeleaf variable but would you really consider good practice putting a complex html code in an element attribute? (th:with="/*HTML code*/")